# Find $z_{st}$ using the chain rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $z=xy+\ln(x^2+y^2)$ and $x=2s+t$ and $y=st$. Find $z_{st}$ using the chain rule.

$z_s=(y+\frac {2x}{x^2+y^2})(2)+(x+\frac {2y}{x^2+y^2})(t)=2y+xt+\frac {4x+2ty}{x^2+y^2}$

$z_{st}=(t+\frac {4-2x}{(x^2+y^2)^2})+(2+\frac {2t-2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2})(s)=t+2s+\frac {4-2x+2st-2sy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Please let me know if what I did is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found $z_s$ correctly, and one way you could proceed after that is to write

$z_s=2(y+v)+(x+w)t$ where $v=\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}$ and $w=\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}$; so

$z_{st}=2(s+v_t)+(x+w)\cdot1+(1+w_t)t$, where you can find $v_t$ and $w_t$ the same way you found $z_s$.

(After that, you want to substitute for x and y to get your answer in terms of s and t.)